# Integration of salesforce for file uploads and insert

Tags: integration, dml, fileupload, database.insert

Is there any way to upload, insert files from any excel sheets(google sheets, MS,...) into salesforce records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce has several useful APIs for getting data in to, and out of, Salesforce, available on a cornucopia of platforms. Simply use a search engine with something like "[some application] salesforce integration." For example, I found the [Data Connector for Salesforce](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/data_connector_for_salesforce/857627895310) app that integrations Google Sheets with Salesforce by typing *google sheets salesforce integration* into Google. It's just a matter of finding the product/service/app that suits your needs and, if necessary, budget (not all apps will be free, of course).